# Multiple buttons activating different methods for an LED strip

Tags: arduino-mega, led, c++, button

I am trying to use different buttons to activate different methods for an LED strip. However, when one button is pressed after another has been pressed, I want it to interrupt the first buttons method and begin the second. For example: one button sends a rainbow pattern through the LED strip when pressed, however, while it is cycling through the rainbow, the second button is pressed which sends a white cycle through the LED strip. There will be 24 buttons total. I have gotten this to work with 2 buttons but am having trouble getting it to work for a third. The code is below:

```
     void loop(){

       if (digitalRead(inPin(1)) == HIGH && lastState == LOW){//if button has just been pressed
           stopCycle();
           theaterChaseRainbow(50);
       }
       if (digitalRead(inPin(2)) == HIGH){
           stopCycle();
           theaterChase(strip.Color(127, 127, 127), 50); // White
       }
       if (digitalRead(inPin(3)) == HIGH){
           stopCycle();
           rainbowCycle(0); 
       }

     }

     //Theatre-style crawling lights.
void theaterChase(uint32_t c, uint8_t wait) {
  for (int j=0; j<100; j++) {  //do 100 cycles of chasing
    if (digitalRead (inPin(1)) == LOW) { //checks that other button(s) have not been pressed
      if (digitalRead (inPin(3) == LOW)){
      for (int q=0; q < 3; q++) {
        for (int i=0; i < strip.numPixels(); i=i+3) {
          strip.setPixelColor(i+q, c);    //turn every third pixel on
        }
        strip.show();

        delay(wait);

        for (int i=0; i < strip.numPixels(); i=i+3) {
          strip.setPixelColor(i+q, 0);        //turn every third pixel off
        }
      }
    }
    }
  }
}

void rainbow(uint8_t wait) {
  int i, j;

  for (j=0; j < 384; j++) {   
   if (digitalRead (inPin(2)) == LOW) { // 3 cycles of all 384 colors in the wheel
    if (digitalRead (inPin(3) == LOW)){
    for (i=0; i < strip.numPixels(); i++) {
      strip.setPixelColor(i, Wheel( (i + j) % 384));
    }  
    strip.show();   // write all the pixels out
    delay(wait);
   }
   }  
  }
}

uint32_t Wheel(uint16_t WheelPos)
{
  byte r, g, b;
  switch(WheelPos / 128)
  {
    case 0:
      r = 127 - WheelPos % 128;   //Red down
      g = WheelPos % 128;      // Green up
      b = 0;                  //blue off
      break; 
    case 1:
      g = 127 - WheelPos % 128;  //green down
      b = WheelPos % 128;      //blue up
      r = 0;                  //red off
      break; 
    case 2:
      b = 127 - WheelPos % 128;  //blue down 
      r = WheelPos % 128;      //red up
      g = 0;                  //green off
      break; 
  }
  return(strip.Color(r,g,b));
}

void rainbowCycle(uint8_t wait) {
  uint16_t i, j;

  for (j=0; j < 384 * 5; j++) {     // 5 cycles of all 384 colors in the wheel
    if (inPin(1) == LOW) {
      if (inPin(2) == LOW) {
    for (i=0; i < strip.numPixels(); i++) {
      // tricky math! we use each pixel as a fraction of the full 384-color wheel
      // (thats the i / strip.numPixels() part)
      // Then add in j which makes the colors go around per pixel
      // the % 384 is to make the wheel cycle around
      strip.setPixelColor(i, Wheel( ((i * 384 / strip.numPixels()) + j) % 384) );
    }  
    strip.show();   // write all the pixels out
    delay(wait);

      }
    }
  }
}

void stopCycle(){
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < strip.numPixels(); i++) {
      strip.setPixelColor(i, 0);
    }  
    strip.show();   // write all the pixels out
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside each inner loop, just test the switches and `return` if they are pressed.

eg.

```C++
//Theatre-style crawling lights.
void theaterChase(uint32_t c, uint8_t wait) {
  for (int j=0; j<100; j++) {  //do 100 cycles of chasing
    for (int q=0; q < 3; q++) {
      for (int i=0; i < strip.numPixels(); i=i+3)
      {
        strip.setPixelColor(i+q, c);    //turn every third pixel on
      }
      strip.show();
      delay(wait);

      // give up if switches pressed
      if (digitalRead (inPin(1)) == HIGH || 
          digitalRead (inPin(2)) == HIGH ||
          digitalRead (inPin(3)) == HIGH )
        return;

      for (int i=0; i < strip.numPixels(); i=i+3) {
        strip.setPixelColor(i+q, 0);        //turn every third pixel off
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

> am having trouble getting it to work for a third

If that doesn't help please explain the nature of this "trouble".

---

You may need to debounce the switch presses. And you may need to wait for them to release the switch, eg.

```C++
 if (digitalRead(inPin(1)) == HIGH && lastState == LOW){//if button has just been pressed
           stopCycle();
           while (digitalRead(inPin(1)) == HIGH)
              {  }   // wait for switch release
           delay (10);  // debounce
           theaterChaseRainbow(50);
       }
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution but is there a way to move the return statement to the loop? This way, I could call theatreChase multiple times with different buttons at different paramenters.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "move the return statement to the loop". Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I would normally do this (pseudocode):

```
void loop() {
    static state=state_off;
    if (button_1_pushed) {
        state=state_1;
    } elseif (button_2_pushed) {
        state=state_2;
    }
    if (state==state_off) {
        turn_all_leds_off();
    } elseif (state==state_2) {
        shownextframe_rainbow();
    } elseif (state==state_2) {
        shownextframe_chaser();
    }
    delay(1);
}
```

In shownextframe_chaser/shownextframe_rainbow, I would probably work out what should be shown based on the current millis() - e.g. if your chaser has 10 lights, and you want it to pulse over 1 second, then each led should be on for 100 millis, so at any instant, the led that should be on is `(millis()/100)%10` (assuming the led's are numbered for 0 to 9).